# Different object pointer value and its this pointer

Tags: c++, aix, xlc

basically, I wrote a class with another class array atributte inside, I mean:

```
class MyClass
{
  unsigned long long x_;
  bool y_;

  public:
  MyClass & operator=(const MyClass & mc)
  {
    x_ = mc.x_;
    y_ = mc.y_;
    return *this;
  }
};

class MyOtherClass
{
  MyClass myClass_[9];

  public:
  MyOtherClass & operator=(const MyOtherClass & mc)
  {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
      myClass_[i] = mc.myClass_[i];
    }
    return *this;
  }
};
```

all of this implemented in a shared library.

I use second class in a second library like:

```
void ThridClass::foo( )
{
  MyOtherClass c1;
  MyOtherClass c2;
  c1 = c2;
}
```

in a 64bit compilation mode with xlC_7, with no alignment pragmas, no optimization, non `virtual` functions, etc, running on an Aix system.

These are the compiler options I used in both libraries:

```
-q64 -bernotok -g -M -qflag=i:w
```

and these are linker options:

```
-brtl -bernotok -G
```

When I debug the program using dbx and ask for `c1.myClass_[0]` address I got one value. But, if I strace the execution inside `MyOtherClass.operator=()` function, I get another address for this attribute pointer.

```
(dbx) p &c1.myClass_[0]
0x0ffffffffffe6a20
(dbx) s
stopped in operator=(const MyOtherClass &)
(dbx) p &myClass_[0]
0x0ffffffffffe69c0
```

This problem doesn't apperar on Linux and works fine.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the "problem" you're talking about? Does it crash or give unexpected results?

Comment: Both, if the array is big enough, the stack frame crash and core is dumped because any asignment inside the operator=( ) function is made in smaller address.

Comment: that's just a consequence of having too many objects on the stack, resulting in a stack overflow. I don't know what you mean by "any assignment inside the operator=( ) function is made in smaller address" though.

Comment: My initial guess is that somehow something changed from the time you built the shared library to when you built the executable.  Or there is something funny in your header that both are using.

Comment: @Seth

Sorry: Outside the operator=( ) function, each array item has correct address. But, inside operator=( ) function, each array item has a smaller address:

Outside the operator=( )

&c1.myClass_[0] = 0x0ffffffffffe6a20
&c1.myClass_[1] = 0x0ffffffffffe6a30
&c1.myClass_[2] = 0x0ffffffffffe6a40

and so on, but inside the operator= function, adresses point to smaller address:

&c1.myClass_[0] = 0x0ffffffffffe69c0
&c1.myClass_[1] = 0x0ffffffffffe6890
&c1.myClass_[2] = 0x0ffffffffffe67a0 ...

if there are a lot of items, address became over stack frame and corrupts it

Answer (score 1):

Just ditch your copy assignment and copy constructor definitions- the implicit compiler-generated ones will be more than sufficient.

Comment: Quick question: for a compiler-generated assignment operator for classes that have arrays of objects which have an _explicit_ assignment operator, is the assignment operator of each of those objects called when the parent object is assigned? Or does it just do a bitwise copy of the memory of the array?

Comment: @Seth: It calls `operator=`. All the special member functions are defined recursively.

Comment: I wrote a quick test and seems like it doesn't call the `operator =` of the objects inside... I wonder now how all my programs worked when I had a `vector` in my class and I copied the class around without copy constructor! (Or maybe I always either wrote the copy constructor or passed around by reference. It must have come to me naturally)

Comment: @Shahbaz: The language will not do a bitwise copy. You likely just wrote a flawed test where the copy was ellided by RVO/NRVO.

Comment: @DeadMG, since I can't write the code here, I will edit your post, put it there for you to see and you can reject the edit if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your operator= you return inside the loop

```
MyOtherClass & MyOtherClass::operator=(const MyOtherClass & mc)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            myClass_[i] = mc.myClass_[i];
            return *this; ////                Move this outside the loop.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would this cause the symptoms he's talking about? `&myClass_[0]` should always be the same.

Comment: It's a good catch. But the `for` loop is always executed in this case; so it will never happen that `*this` is not returned.

Comment: Sorry Dans, it was a transcription error. The return statment is outside the loop